# Getting values from properties file

Tags: java, file

- I have a java code to append the values into my properties file
- My properties file will have an entry like this.
- key1 = host,port,orcl,username,password
- key2 = host,port,orcl,username,password
- key3 = host,port,orcl,username,password and so on...

these key1, key2 and key3 are connection names.

- Before doing an entry into properties file, first i have to check whether the file has given connection name entry. i mean, if user again entering the value using key1 or key2 or key3 connection name, it has to give an alert saying that this connection name is available so try with another name.

Here is my java code to make an entry into file:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
       try
       {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+":"+port+"/"+service,username,password);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            if (con!=null)
            {
                 session.setAttribute(username, con); 
                 out.println("Connected Successfully");          
                 PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my properties file", true)));
                 out1.println(cname+" = "+host+","+port+","+service+","+username+","+password);
                 out1.close();
            }
            else
            {
                 out.println("Error in getting connection");
            }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, why are you putting a database connection in the session? Can't see thats a good idea.

Comment: that is for some other use. that line doesn't relate with the question which i asked now. may i know why i got down vote for this question?

Comment: downvoted because the question is unclear and shows little research effort.

Comment: in which line its unclear and where you want to do research?

Comment: You stated your aims and then posted code that makes no effort to achieve them. You haven't asked a question specific to a problem you're having. Try and write some code to accomplish your task and if it isn't working then *ask a question*.

Answer (score 4):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load("pathToPropertiesFile");


String key; //This is the key which user will enter
String propKey = prop.getProperty(key);
if(propKey == null)
{
    // Key is not present so enter the key into the properties file
      prop.setProperty("keyName", key);
}
else
{
    // Throw error saying key already exists
      out.println("Key "+key+" already exists.");
}
```

Refer [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) for more information and example on Properties in Java

**Updated**: 
Okay, if you wish to check whether such value is present (irrespective) of any key, then use this code

```
   // Ignoring the loading of the properties file
   // Assuming properties file is loaded in "prop"
   Enumeration keySet = prop.keys();
   String key; // This is the key which user will enter
   boolean keyExists = false;
   while(keySet.hasMoreElements())
   {
       String keyName = (String) keySet.nextElement();
       String keyValue = prop.getProperty(keyName);
       if( key.equals(keyValue))  //Check against all the keys' value present
       {
           keyExists = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   if(keyExists)
   {
       //throw error
   }
   else
   {
       //insert key
   }
```

The approach is to get all the keys present and check against its values. If the value present in the properties file is same as that user entered or otherwise then you know what is to be done

If you want to make the check against the KeyName then just change the *if condition in the loop*

```
if( key.equals(keyName))  //Check against all the key Name present in the properties file
{
 keyExists = true;
 break;
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: am not storing the value with constant key. every time the key value gets changed. it can be key1, key2 or key3.

Comment: So enter the `key` (manually or programmatically) as appropriate.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Yeah while entering the key make sure you don't repeat the keyname (enter programmaticall as @AndrewThompson mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class. It has some pertinent methods that may be of use;

```
load()
save()
setProperty()
containsKey()
```